# C Static variables on function inputs

Tags: c, static, initialization

I'd like to save an input to a function and manipulate it across multiple calls. However, if I do the following...

```
int testFunc(char *toString) {
        static char *toChange = toString;
        static int counter = 0;

        toChange[counter] = 'A';
        printf("String is being corrupted... %s\n", toChange);
        counter++;

        return 0;
}
```

I get an error saying that the input `toChange` cannot be set to a non-static variable. I have been trying to figure out how to get around this but I cannot find any answers.

Comment: You should initiate your pointer to NULL, so, in the first call, you copy the string to your local variable, then, after that, you do not change its content anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables shall be initialized by constant expressions.

Write instead something like

```
 int testFunc(char *toString) {
    static char *toChange;
    static int counter;

    if ( toChange == NULL || toString == NULL ) 
    {
        toChange = toString;
        counter = 0;
    } 

    toChange[counter] = 'A';
    printf("String is being corrupted... %s\n", toChange);
    counter++;

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: It would be even better to explicitly initialize `toChange` to `NULL`! But I think this will be the default, anyway (`static` data default to zero, I think?)

Comment: I am not sure if every compiler initializes local variables to zero. I recommend you never count on that.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes It is not just a local variable it is also a static variable and static variables are initialized by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
int testFunc(char *toString) {
    static char *toChange = NULL;
    static int counter = 0;
    if (toChange == NULL) {
        toChange = (char*)malloc(strlen(toString) + 1);
        memset(toChange, 0, strlen(toString) + 1);
        strcpy(toChange, toString);
    }
    toChange[counter] = 'A';
    printf("String is being corrupted... %s\n", toChange);
    counter++;
    return 0;
}
```